# Converter --> Convert DateTime to HH:mm:ss format

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display a hh:mm:ss format but i always get the full date displayed.

Is there something wrong / missing from my Convertor Class / Dependency Properties?
I only receive the Datetime.now display, how to change this to 00:00:00?

What i actually want is to display 00:00:00 as initialization. Later it increments trough timers.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    DownTime="{Binding DownTime, Converter={StaticResource  DateTimeConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter=\{0:hh:mm:ss\}}
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**Dependency Properties:**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DownTimeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DownTime", typeof(DateTime), typeof(RegistrationButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

public DateTime DownTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DownTimestandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DownTimeProperty, value); }
    }
```

**Convertor class:**

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(String))]
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        return dt;

    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
        {
            return resultDateTime;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which xaml element actually holds the datetime binding?

Comment: ListBoxItemTemplate ==> DataTemplate

Comment: I didn't mean this. I meant something like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ... }" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use StringFormat

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DownTime, StringFormat={}{0:"hh:mm:ss"}}" />
```

**EDIT**

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day.

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) Represents a time interval.

They have many similar methods, especially the ones to add or remove hours/mins/seconds and I think that's what you want for this case.

Comment: I was going to say exactly the same. I currently have it working

Comment: Seems i do no really want DateTime.Now as initialization but how to get 00:00:00 as start?

Comment: @Jackz It seems you should use a TimeSpan instead of a DateTime because you aren't representing a Date, you're representing an Interval

Comment: So to record hh:mm:ss trough Timer / Stopwatch a Interval is the best DateType? I used String before and then switched to DateTime.